# Sound does not work on Linux Mint 19.2 newly installed

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I tried force-reload pulseaudio, did a system reboot.....all to no avail. But then I tried the following:

```
phonon@DALEK:~$ apt-get install alsa-utils -y

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)

E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

phonon@DALEK:~$ sudo apt-get install alsa-utils -y

[sudo] password for phonon: 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
alsa-utils is already the newest version (1.1.3-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 251 not upgraded.

phonon@DALEK:~$ systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio

Created symlink /home/phonon/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/pulseaudio.service → /usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service.
Created symlink /home/phonon/.config/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/pulseaudio.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket.
Job for pulseaudio.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service" and "journalctl --user -xe" for details.

phonon@DALEK:~$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-09-25 08:44:40 PDT; 26s ago
  Process: 2128 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2128 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 25 08:44:40 DALEK systemd[1149]: pulseaudio.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Sep 25 08:44:40 DALEK systemd[1149]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.

Sep 25 08:44:40 DALEK systemd[1149]: Stopped Sound Service.
Sep 25 08:44:40 DALEK systemd[1149]: pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 25 08:44:40 DALEK systemd[1149]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 25 08:44:40 DALEK systemd[1149]: Failed to start Sound Service.
```

So I'm confused as to what the error codes mean here and how to fix this problem. I tried to reinstall pulseaudio but that messes up cinnamon.

I know it's NOT a hardware failure because I tested my sound in BIOS and it works.

Upon suggestion I tried this:

```
phonon@DALEK:~$ systemctl status sound.target
● sound.target - Sound Card
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sound.target; static; vendor preset: enab
   Active: active since Wed 2019-09-25 15:49:57 PDT; 16h ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Sep 25 15:49:57 DALEK systemd[1]: Reached target Sound Card.
lines 1-6/6 (END)...skipping...
● sound.target - Sound Card
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sound.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active since Wed 2019-09-25 15:49:57 PDT; 16h ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Sep 25 15:49:57 DALEK systemd[1]: Reached target Sound Card.
```

Comment: What does `inxi -A` show?

Comment: Device-1: AMD driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: AMD Family 15h Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-54-generic

Comment: You shouldn't need to start the pulseaudio service (not running on my Mint 19.2 system). Are you getting any error messages in the kernel logs? What about `systemctl status sound.target`? (please add to your question).

Comment: Here's a link to one of the Mint Forum users who helped me with sound issues: https://mreen.000webhostapp.com/SoundFixTips.html